# How to do Regex for a href?

Tags: python, html, regex, post, get

```
<div class="user-info" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;z-index:1">

<a href="/kjrphotography" target="_blank">

<img class="photo_user" src="http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_507998691_75sq_1376497436.jpg" width="40" height="40" title="kjrphotography" border="0">

</a>

<span class="usertag" style="display: none;">@kjrphotography</span>

</div>
```

So I have sort of seperated this a bit, basically i'm trying to find where "user-info" is and then i need to grab what the a href is. In this case /kjrphotography or the span element with the usertag class.

If someone could help me with this please I appreciate it.

I have this so far but I know this isn't close to right

```
userdata = re.findall(ur"<div class=\"user-info\"><\/div>",curlData)
```

Comment: I would rather use a HTML parsing lib than regex. Beautiful Soup for example: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: BeautifulSoup 4 is now just an lxml wrapper, so you might as well use lxml directly

Comment: so even using regex to grab the usertag span field? Nobody could give me that? I'm using curl so I would much rather keep it this way.

Comment: What is the full HTML?

Comment: You can use Javascript or jQuery to grab href inside "user-info".

If you want to pass href to python code, then you can use Ajax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely best and easiest to use an HTML instead, with `html` being your HTML page - here's an example using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.select('.user-info a')[0]['href']
# /kjrphotography
```

You'll find it easier and far more robust than trying to treat HTML as strings...

Alternatively:

```
for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='user-info'):
    print 'href:', info.find('a', href=True)['href']
    print 'user:', info.find('span', class_='usertag').text

#href: /kjrphotography
#user: @kjrphotography
```

Comment: How do I install this for windows 7 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import html
xml = html.fragments_fromstring("""<div class="user-info" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;z-index:1">

<a href="/kjrphotography" target="_blank">

<img class="photo_user" src="http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_507998691_75sq_1376497436.jpg" width="40" height="40" title="kjrphotography" border="0">

</a>

<span class="usertag" style="display: none;">@kjrphotography</span>

</div>""")[0]

xml.find('span').text
```

returns `'@kjphotography'`